# Does {spatstat}'s `nearestsegment()` produce imprecise results?

Tags: r, r-sf, spatstat

Although, the figure is rather small, one can see that several points/*events* (lightred) do not lie on colored line segments and vice a versa. Where does this deviation come from? Is there a way to improve my procedure?

Why I am doing this? **Overall goal:**

1. Attach point weights as edge weights to respective line segments;
2. then plot line segments color or weight scaled (even better invent sth. like a heat map).

```r
# Smallest reproducible example 
library(spatstat)
data("chicago")
N <- npoints(chicago)
# create some weights, later useful 
marks(chicago) <- rnorm(N, 5, 2) 

# find to each point nearest line segment 
idx <- nearestsegment(as.ppp(chicago), as.psp(chicago))

# not to my suprise this is quite similar to: 
# (i) retrieve network 
lns <- sf::st_as_sf(maptools::as.SpatialLines.psp(
  spatstat.geom::as.psp(chicago)))
# (ii) retrieve event coords 
events <- data.frame(xcoords = chicago[["data"]]$x,
                     ycoords = chicago[["data"]]$y)
# convert 
pnts <- sf::st_as_sf(events, coords = c("xcoords", "ycoords"))

# get nearest feature 
idx2 <- sf::st_nearest_feature(pnts, lns)

# one deviation 
which(idx != idx2)
#> [1] 1
idx[1]
#> [1] 37
idx2[1]
#> [1] 38

# my overall goal is to transmit the point weights to the 
# respective line segments. With those edge weights I would like to 
# plot some maps, therefore: 

# (I) create igraph object from chicago: 
library(igraph)

edges <- cbind(chicago[["domain"]][["from"]], chicago[["domain"]][["to"]])
chicago_net <- graph_from_edgelist(edges)
adjm <- as.matrix(as_adjacency_matrix(chicago_net))

g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjm, 'undirected')

vertex_attr(g, name = 'x') <- chicago[["domain"]]$vertices[["x"]]
vertex_attr(g, name = 'y') <- chicago[["domain"]]$vertices[["y"]]

# (II) add point weights as edge weights to graph according to idx: 
weights <- c(rep(NA, nrow(chicago[["domain"]]$lines[["ends"]])))
weights[idx2] <- chicago[["data"]]$marks
E(g)$weight <- weights

# finally plot g via ggraph [same result with igraph.plot()]
library(ggraph)

ggraph(g, x = vertex_attr(g)$x, y = vertex_attr(g)$y) +
  geom_edge_link0(aes(color = weight)) +
  # sth. practical from here: 
  # https://ggraph.data-imaginist.com/reference/scale_edge_colour.html
  scale_edge_colour_viridis() +
  geom_point(data = events, mapping = aes(x = xcoords, y = ycoords), 
             alpha = 0.3, size = 2, shape = 20, col = "red") +
  theme_void()
```

gives

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

FYI `?nearestsegment`'s *description* is as follows

> Given a point pattern and a line segment pattern, this function finds the nearest line segment for each point.

---

Sooner or later, everything I do with `{spatstat}` works as it should, hence I think I am doing a great mistake.

Comment: have you taken into account that the code only takes the first one line segment found when you execute the `nearestsegment()` [this is my assumption]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "first one line sgment". Could you please specify?

Comment: I [added](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fl38jszid834am5/test01.png?dl=0) a geom_text to your plot to see correspondings between points and segments, and I dont see labels match; some do, but some dont; some points sit next to the nearest segment, some segments sitting alone altogether, and some points sit far away from their corresponding segment

Comment: Exactly, this is where my confusion comes from

Comment: seems like an indexing issue; perhaps you screwed vector indices somewhere; what disturbs me is that you take length for weights from `domain$lines$ends`, but the vertices themselves from `domain$vertices$x`

Comment: Yeah, an indexing issue was my inital thought, but couldn't find. Where? Regarding your latter point, I think with this everything is fine. In general three things: events, network nodes, network edges. General note on the example chicago: # line segments (edges) > # nodes (vertices) > # events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove adjacency matrix calculation; it reorders segments of the graph
correct `g` assignment:

```
g <- graph_from_edgelist(edges)
```

Comment: Thank you, I would never have found this!